# jQuery plugins - is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, conflicting-libraries

I use a number of jQuery plugins on my site (owl carousel for example) which work fine everywhere except one page where I require another script which loads content from another site into an iframe.

On the problem page I am getting errors for all my jQuery plugins, i.e. owl carousel:

`$(...).owlCarousel is not a function`

I have tried running jQuery in no conflict mode:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
    $(function(){
        $('.carousel').owlCarousel({
            items: 3,
            lazyLoad: true
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But I still get the same error.

I have double checked my filepaths are correct and the files are being loaded in the correct order. They are:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mysite.com/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mysite.com/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mysite.com/custom.js"></script><!-- call to owl carousel-->
```

In the body I have a placeholder div for the iframe to be loaded into. Then I include the script for loading the iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mysite.com/iframe-script.js">
```

And after this some simple javascript config settings for the iframe and that's it.

The iframe script is a few thousand lines unminified and a bit beyond my understanding of javascript but, from what I can tell it uses its own custom variable for referencing jQuery which is why I don't think the issue is a jQuery conflict issue.

jQuery still works in `mysite.com/custom.js`, i.e. all onclick events fire with no errors. So jQuery is working. Just none of the jQuery plugins I am using.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Something is loading jQuery *again*. Reloading the library will undo all of the plugin scripts that have already been loaded.

Comment: Try putting the `jQuery.noConflict();` after the owlCarousel loading...

Comment: Are you sure that you have an HTML tag with `.carousel` class?

Comment: @Pointy I think you maybe onto something here. Is there a way I can check if this is happening?

Comment: Well, it depends on how your code gets put together, but what I've been able to do is a sort of "triangulation" process, adding little script blocks with marker `console.log()` calls to figure out where in the document things go wrong. It's not a sophisticated process but it gets the job done.

Comment: Before that you might just get to the page with the developer tools "Network" tab open, and see what URLs are fetched.

Comment: I just solved a similar issue with another plugin. It turned out the plugin required another plugin aside of JQuery which I was not aware about. After some debugging, I figured out and things worked.